How do I replace my Chromebook OS with Linux (Ubuntu 22.04)?
I do not like The Chromebook environment; it is too invasive. Thus, I want to completely remove that Chromebook Operating System and replace it with Ubuntu (22.04 LTS). I have used  Ubuntu OSs since 2006. Ubuntu OSs have helped me restore old PCs & Laptops and made them viable again. However, I have done this only with the transition from Windows to Ubuntu. This is an effort to do the transition from Chromebook to Ubuntu (22.04 LTS). So, how?
PS> I have tried to use Crouton to no success. Thus, I am looking for an even better way.

By the way 22.04 has sound issues on many chromebooks. These issues are solved in 24.04 with the sound script mentioned in the other answer
